# Why PHP removes some characters from LONG base64 image sent by POST?

Tags: php, swift

I have a PHP file that I use to convert `base64` images into actual `files` and store them on my server.

The base64 images are sent to the PHP in an `array` via `POST` from a `Swift iOS` app.

However, when I receive the base64 strings on the server/PHP, there seems to be some data missing from the base64 string. They seem to be stuff like `+` sign etc.

**For example:**

This is what I have in the console client side:

```text
/pKhpAXVAQlKriLxte79N9f8K2/7d+ZnCEU6uIjK7w3s7e61/G9zrPt5S+X2f//Z
```

But by the time I receive this on the server, I get this:

```text
/pKhpAXVAQlKriLxte79N9f8K2/7d ZnCEU6uIjK7w3s7e61/G9zrPt5S X2f//Z
```

If you noticed, there seems to be some `+` signs missing. I'm, not striping anything at any point in my code.

So why am I having this issue?

This is my PHP code:

```php
$imagesArray = $_POST['imagesArray'];
$arr = json_decode($imagesArray, true);

foreach ($arr as $value) {
    $base64_string = "data:image/jpeg;base64,".$value;
    //$base64_string = preg_replace('/\s+/', '+', $base64_string);
    $fp = fopen("myText.txt","wb");
    fwrite($fp,$base64_string);
    fclose($fp);
}
```

I also tried to use this code `$base64_string = preg_replace('/\s+/', '+', $base64_string);` and add the missing `+` signs back in the base64 strings and I managed to convert the base64 images into files and saved them on the server BUT when I look at the saved image files, they have massive Grey lines on them!

for example:

**Original base64 image:**

[image]

**Same image Converted to file and saved on the server using the code above:**

[image]

Here's the Swift code that sends the data:

```swift
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: NSURL(string: "https://example.com/upload.php")! as URL)
request.httpMethod = "POST"

let postString = "imagesArray=\(String(describing: imagesArray))"
request.httpBody = postString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)

let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) {
    data, response, error in

    if error != nil {
        print("error=\(String(describing: error))")
        return
    }

    //print("response = \(String(describing: response))")
    let responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
    let result = responseString!
    if (result != "success") {
        print(responseString!)
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1.0) {
            self.hideLoade()
        }
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1.5) {
            self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
            SCLAlertView().showSuccess("Success", subTitle: result as String)
        }
    } else {
        print(responseString!)
    }
}

task.resume()
```

Comment: `+` being converted to a space corresponds to URL decoding. Maybe some part of the communication process is doing that?

Comment: @El_Vanja, yes, but I can't figure out where because I'm not doing that anywhere in my codes. both Swift and PHP. I can see the actual base64 in the console in the Xcode and it all looks good. I can simply copy/paste the strings in the browser and see the images fine. but by the time they hit the server, the + is missing!

Comment: maybe you should add the code that (tries to) send the data....?

Comment: @Luuk, you mean the Swift Code?

Comment: Probably a good idea to tag Swift as well, since the question concerns the communication between the apps.

Answer (score 2):

As noted in the comments, base64 contains characters that are "special" to URLs, so in order to put base64 on a URL you need to modify the encoding slightly to make it url-safe:

```
function base64url_encode($bin) {
        return str_replace(['+', '/', '='], ['-', '_', ''], base64_encode($bin));
}

function base64url_decode($str) {
        return base64_decode(str_replace(['-', '_'], ['+', '/'], $str));
}
```

I'm not sure what the equivalent Swift code would be, but it should be simple to implement.

That said, putting large blobs of data into the URL is problematic in a number of ways, including URL length limits, having all this data crammed into your server logs, as well as the fact that base64 encoding increases the size of the data by 33%.

This should definitely be a POST or PUT request with the image data in the request *body*, not the URL.

Answer (score 1):

(Irrespective of the actual solution, consider using `multipart/form-data` forms instead and get rid of the base64 encoding.)

---

This is one of the rare cases where PHP is doing the right thing. The problem is on the sending side, specifically here:

```swift
let postString = "imagesArray=\(String(describing: imagesArray))"
request.httpBody = postString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
```

You are interpolating the data directly into the form data, without observing the escaping rules of URL-encoded forms. You are lucky this is just base64 and not a string of arbitrary characters, otherwise it would be able to inject arbitrary parameters into the form data.

Try this instead (adapted from [this article](https://medium.com/@serge.works.io/swift-how-to-create-a-http-post-request-with-application-x-www-form-urlencoded-body-bfd9cd26d6d5), as I don’t actually know any Swift):

```swift
var formData = URLComponents()
formData.queryItems = [URLQueryItem(name: "imagesArray", value: String(describing: imagesArray))]
request.httpBody = formData.query?.data(using: .utf8)
```

Comment: still have the same issue of + signs being missing when the base64 hits the PHP!

Comment: Which did you try, the older version or the newer?

Comment: The new version.